# How to allow external user to see Outlook calendar for a room

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, exchange-2016

Within my organization, each division maintains their own Microsoft Exchange Server (we're running 2016). I have one person from another division (and therefore on a different Exchange server) who frequently needs to reserve some of the rooms managed by our division. This is particularly challenging, because he can't see the availability of the room to know when it's available. The solution so far has been for him to ask me to check the Outlook calendar and reserve the room for him.

Is there a way for us to allow him to see the room's calendar so he can book himself? Even if he can see the room's availability without being able to interact, that would simplify things a lot. I don't actually have any control over our server myself, but I want to see if there's a possible solution before asking my IT folks who will most certainly just say, "No, you can't do that," without even trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to log in to the room mailbox and share its caledar to the external user like below:

[image]